# Rails - change form action based on radio selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, radio-button

I'm a Rails noob. I won't lie. I've been tasked with taking two forms and turning them into one dynamic form. This is a Login/Sign Up form. The only issue I have is how to handle the Rails portion of the code. Using jQuery, I could have easily replaced HTML form actions, but how would I approach replacing the action/destination in the rails code based on a login or sign up radio selection.

```
<%= form_tag login_path, :id => '_login_form' do %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag sign_up_path, :id => '_sign_up_form' do %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see two options to solve your problem.

Using javascript you can change the action of a form, based on the radio button selected.

```
$("#radio").change(function() {
  var action = $(this).val() == "some_value" ? "login" : "sign_up";
  $("#your-form").attr("action", "/" + action);
});
```

Or you can handle both methods in a single action and treat each of the options separatedly

```
#view
<p> <%= radio_button_tag :option, "login" %> Orange </p>
<p> <%= radio_button_tag  :option, "sign_up" %> Peach </p>

#controller
if params[:option] == "login"
  #do login
elsif params[:option] == "sign_up"
  #do sign up
end
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How does the :option then go into the controller?

Answer (score 1):

If the object is to use only one form, but to have different submit buttons go to different form actions, than that seems like a perfect use case for the `formaction` attribute on submit inputs.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#formaction)

Note that `formmethod` is another attribute, if all you want to do is change the method.

Here's a idea of what you might do:

```rb
  <%= submit_tag('Sign Up', formaction: 'user#create', formmethod: 'POST') %>

  <%= submit_tag('Log In', formaction: 'user#login', formmethod: 'POST') %>
```

Any of these form* attributes take precedence over the form action.